# Unable to import field object from Scrapy Items.py file

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use the following import statement to bring in a field to a `Scrapy` spider:

```
from test.items import fixture
```

In this instance `test.py` is a `Scrapy` script  which is contained within the folder path:

```
C:\Python27\mrscrap\mrscrap\spiders\test.py
```

The file Items.py is one level up from this and is contained in the folder path:

```
C:\Python27\mrscrap\mrscrap\items.py
```

This line of code produces the error:

```
No module named items
```

Am I using the correct filename in the logic `'test.items'`? Do I have the file `items.py` in the correct place?

My full code is this:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from mrscrap.items import Fixture
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import re

class GoalSpider(Spider):
    name = "goal"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.whoscored.com/',
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        return Request(
            url="http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney",
            callback=self.parse_fixtures
        )

    def parse_fixtures(self,response):
        sel = response.selector
        for tr in sel.css("table#player-fixture>tbody>tr"):
             item = Fixture()
             item['tournament'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="tournament"]/span/a/text()').extract()
             item['date'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
             item['team home'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="team home "]/a/text()').extract()
             yield item

execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal'])
```

And the class within Items.py is written as this:

```
class Fixture(Item):
    tournament = Field()
    date = Field()
    team_home = Field()
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe you changed folder names in meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

**First answer for general scrapy projects, where you run the scrapy command**

It's a bit hard to follow what `test` is a reference to, since your project seem to be named `mrscrap`. If you're trying to import the `fixture` reference from the `items.py` file, the statement should read:

```
from mrscrap.items import fixture
```

This requires a `__init__.py` file being present in `mrscrap\`, but it should be there by default after creating the project with scrapy.

**Running the scraper directly from its directory (as in the update)**

You can do this with a relative import, as shown in [PEP 328](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports).

```
from ..items import fixture
```

This require that you're in a currently active package, so you'll have to have an `__init__.py` file (although empty) in your spiders directory.

Comment: there is an __init__.py file in the same place as items.py...the above code however produces the error 'no module named mrscrap.items'. this is slightly different from the error 'no module named items' that using 'from test.items import fixture generates. i dont get what i am doing wrong?

Comment: the __init__.py file is empty though. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Where are you running your project from when you're getting the error? Are you running the `scrapy` command from the first `mrscrap\` directory? (and not `mrscrap\mrscrap\`). And are you actually trying to import the symbol `fixture` from items.py, or are you trying to use some sort of unittest framework?

Comment: i have amended my question to show my full code above. i have tried running the code via F5 - Run Module in the Python IDLE and via Command Prompt. I was initially running the 'scrapy crawl goal' command from the mrscrap/mrscrap location, but I have amended this now to one layer above at mrscrap only and still receive the same error.

Comment: I've updated the answer, although my experience is that it's better to run the spiders through the scrapy tool (with parse and -r / --pipelines etc.) while testing, as it gives you the whole scrapy framework with logging etc. as well.

Comment: @fiskfisk...that throws up an error of 'attempted relative import in non-package'. im still not 100% what this new logic is doing or what the problem is with the old logic?

Comment: As I mentions, you'll have to have an `__init__.py` file in your spiders directory. "..items" is a relative import that imports items from the path above the current file. You can also manipulate the path that python checks for libraries to include, but that's a bigger beast - and relative imports should solve it.